# instantiate object inside of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

Im trying to understand why I cannot access the methods on an object that is instantiated inside of a class. For example i'm attempting to build a script that utilizes the python-pptx library and I want to wrap the entire slide creation within a class to abstract it and make it a bit more reusable based on my configuration.

```
class Builder():

    def __init__(self, template='template.pptx', output_file='out.pptx'):
        self.cust_name = ''
        self.author = ''
        self.job_title = ''
        self.present_date = ''
        self.assessment_type = ''
        self.template = template
        self.agenda = ['Overview','Resources']
        self.outfile = output_file
        self.prs = Presentation('template.pptx') <--- This is what im referring to.

    def addAgendaSlide(self):
        agenda_slide = self.prs.add_slide(self.prs.slide_layouts[AGENDA]) <-- When trying to access this
        agenda_slide.shapes.title.text = 'Agenda'
        agenda_slide.placeholders[10].text = 'A test Agenda slide'
        agenda_slide.placeholders[15].top = STANDARD_TOP
        agenda_slide.placeholders[15].left = STANDARD_LEFT
        agenda_slide.placeholders[15].width = 8229600
        agenda_slide.placeholders[15].height = 4572000
        for para in self.agenda:
            p = agenda_slide.placeholders[15].text_frame.add_paragraph()
            p.text = para

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
test.addAgendaSlide()
  File "/dev/pythonpptx/DocMaker/Slides.py", line 89, in addAgendaSlide
agenda_slide = self.prs.add_slide(self.prs.slide_layouts[AGENDA])
AttributeError: 'Presentation' object has no attribute 'add_slide'
```

If I use the same bits of code outside the class it works fine. I do have other methods in the class that are fine, it seems to be my implementation of the Presentation() bit that is messing me up.

The following works fine:

```
prs = Presentation('template.pptx')
agenda_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[AGENDA])
agenda_slide.shapes.title.text = 'Agenda'
agenda_slide.placeholders[15].top = STANDARD_TOP
agenda_slide.placeholders[15].left = STANDARD_LEFT
agenda_slide.placeholders[15].width = 8229600
agenda_slide.placeholders[15].height = 4572000
prs.save('out.pptx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you are forgetting to add `slides` as follows:

```
agenda_slide = self.prs.slides.add_slide(self.prs.slide_layouts[AGENDA])
```

instead of

```
agenda_slide = self.prs.add_slide(self.prs.slide_layouts[AGENDA])
```

Comment: You are awesome. I cant believe i missed that.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept if it has solved the problem :)